# Can not open google chrome stable on elementary os freya

Tags: chrome, elementary-os

I have installed `google-chrome-stable` 64 bit. But it is not opening. My system is Elementary OS Freya 64 bit.

Here is the error code that generate in the terminal.

```
[1:1:0425/175043:ERROR:image_metadata_extractor.cc(111)] Couldn't load                 libexif.
[6234:6234:0425/175043:ERROR:browser_main_loop.cc(199)] GTK theme error: Unable to locate theme engine in module_path: "murrine",
[6234:6234:0425/175043:ERROR:browser_main_loop.cc(199)] GTK theme error: Unable to locate theme engine in module_path: "murrine",
[6234:6234:0425/175043:ERROR:browser_main_loop.cc(199)] GTK theme error: Unable to locate theme engine in module_path: "murrine",
[6234:6234:0425/175043:ERROR:browser_main_loop.cc(199)] GTK theme error: Unable to locate theme engine in module_path: "murrine",
[6234:6234:0425/175043:ERROR:browser_main_loop.cc(199)] GTK theme error: Unable to locate theme engine in module_path: "murrine",
[6234:6234:0425/175043:ERROR:browser_main_loop.cc(199)] GTK theme error: Unable to locate theme engine in module_path: "murrine",
[6234:6234:0425/175043:ERROR:browser_main_loop.cc(199)] GTK theme error: Unable to locate theme engine in module_path: "murrine",
[6234:6234:0425/175043:ERROR:browser_main_loop.cc(199)] GTK theme error: Unable to locate theme engine in module_path: "murrine",
[6234:6234:0425/175043:ERROR:browser_main_loop.cc(199)] GTK theme error: Unable to locate theme engine in module_path: "murrine",
[6234:6234:0425/175043:ERROR:browser_main_loop.cc(199)] GTK theme error: Unable to locate theme engine in module_path: "murrine",
[6234:6234:0425/175043:ERROR:browser_main_loop.cc(199)] GTK theme error: Unable to locate theme engine in module_path: "murrine",
[6234:6234:0425/175043:ERROR:browser_main_loop.cc(199)] GTK theme error: Unable to locate theme engine in module_path: "murrine",
[6234:6234:0425/175043:ERROR:browser_main_loop.cc(199)] GTK theme error: Unable to locate theme engine in module_path: "murrine",
[6234:6234:0425/175043:ERROR:browser_main_loop.cc(199)] GTK theme error: Unable to locate theme engine in module_path: "murrine",
[6234:6234:0425/175043:ERROR:browser_main_loop.cc(199)] GTK theme error: Unable to locate theme engine in module_path: "murrine",
[6234:6234:0425/175043:ERROR:browser_main_loop.cc(199)] GTK theme error: Unable to locate theme engine in module_path: "murrine",
[6234:6234:0425/175043:ERROR:browser_main_loop.cc(199)] GTK theme error: Unable to locate theme engine in module_path: "murrine",
[6234:6234:0425/175043:ERROR:browser_main_loop.cc(199)] GTK theme error: Unable to locate theme engine in module_path: "murrine",
[6234:6234:0425/175043:ERROR:browser_main_loop.cc(199)] GTK theme error: Unable to locate theme engine in module_path: "murrine",
[6234:6234:0425/175043:ERROR:browser_main_loop.cc(199)] GTK theme error: Unable to locate theme engine in module_path: "murrine",
[6234:6234:0425/175043:ERROR:browser_main_loop.cc(199)] GTK theme error: Unable to locate theme engine in module_path: "pixmap",
[6234:6234:0425/175043:ERROR:browser_main_loop.cc(199)] GTK theme error: Unable to locate theme engine in module_path: "pixmap",
[6234:6234:0425/175043:ERROR:browser_main_loop.cc(199)] GTK theme error: Unable to locate theme engine in module_path: "pixmap",
[6234:6234:0425/175043:ERROR:browser_main_loop.cc(199)] GTK theme error: Unable to locate theme engine in module_path: "pixmap",
[6234:6234:0425/175043:ERROR:browser_main_loop.cc(199)] GTK theme error: Unable to locate theme engine in module_path: "murrine",
[6234:6234:0425/175043:ERROR:browser_main_loop.cc(199)] GTK theme error: Unable to locate theme engine in module_path: "pixmap",
[6234:6234:0425/175043:ERROR:browser_main_loop.cc(199)] GTK theme error: Unable to locate theme engine in module_path: "murrine",
[6234:6234:0425/175043:ERROR:browser_main_loop.cc(199)] GTK theme error: Unable to locate theme engine in module_path: "murrine",
[6234:6234:0425/175043:ERROR:browser_main_loop.cc(199)] GTK theme error: Unable to locate theme engine in module_path: "murrine",
Gtk-Message: Failed to load module "canberra-gtk-module"
Aborted (core dumped)
```

I have tried to install `murrine` but the system showed me that this is already in newest version.

Comment: Hmm, I wonder if this should be a bug filed against chrome/chromium?

Comment: How did you fix it? (I have the sane problem)

Comment: I was able to resolve all the errors by installing the i386 versions of the libs it was missing, Got stuck on LibGL.1.so

Answer (score 4):

Looks like Chrome is looking for the Murrine Gtk engine. You should install gtk2-engines-murrine

Comment: System reports that package is already installed, as well as libexif12

Comment: @MuztabaHasanat If Daniel's reply is a valid answer I think he ought to get the Bounty.

Comment: @ned64 This answer does not, in my testing, fix chrome's inability to launch without crashing on Freya. I was able to resolve all console errors with the i386 packages of the missing libs and chrome would still not open

Comment: @ThorSummoner if you're getting errors about i386 packages, that means you've installed the 32bit version of Chrome on a 64bit system. You'll need to download the 64bit version instead.

Comment: What more can I do than install chrome from the 64 bit deb package? Because that's what I did ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: @ThorSummoner are you 100% sure? Does the name of the file say "64bit"? The only reason to get messaging about i386 packages would be because you've installed a 32bit package.

Comment: @MuztabaHasanat how did you fixed it?

Comment: @Gocht I downloaded the 32-bit install package mistakenly. After tried with 64-bit version it was ok. The main problem was whenever I was downloading  the 64-bit version, it was actually downloading the 32-bit version instead. After some attempted 64-bit version finally downloaded.

Answer (score 0):

The chromium package (which is [not the same](https://askubuntu.com/q/6253/250556) as Google's Chrome). But it does work, and it does look and act like chrome, which basically satisfies my use case.

Chromium: https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/chromium-browser/

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have the 64 bit version. If your installed version 32 bit, purge it and then reinstall.

I had a similar issue, turns out I installed the 32 bit when I thought I installed 64 bit.

Comment: Welcome to Unix&Linux SE! [Take a tour](http://unix.stackexchange.com/tour) to get familiar with our philosophy. Unfortunately, the question is not only old, but already solved - plus, your answer clearly ignores the informations contained in the question. Therefore, your answer might get some downvotes. I suggest that you read both question and existing answers more thoroughly before answering.

Comment: I disagree with you @MatthewRock.
Himself faced with the same problem and same errors if start from terminal. I was completely sure that the downloaded version of 64 but is not true. Repeat downloading 64 version of chrome but have same 32 version. I suspect the problem in the browser Midori.
My answer 100% good! ) And my answer different with exist.

Comment: Sorry, but I can not understand you in 100%. Your english is hard for me to read. Anyway, problem is _solved_, and question is old. That were the bullet points of my comment. Your answer itself might have solved the issue, but we have no way of knowing this.